# iOS 9.0 - NSMutableDictionary causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, nsmutabledictionary

My application includes a singleton class represents general data. The latter contains the following **atomic** property :

```
// .h file
@property (atomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *dataDictionary;

// .m file
@synthesize dataDictionary;
```

The dictionary is being used simultaneously from different threads (both setter and getter), and worked as normal without any crashes on iOS 6.0 - 8.4.
Recently I have run the application on iOS 9.0 simulator and it crashed (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) in arbitrary code calling the dictionary `setObject:forKey:` method.

1. Does anyone knows what have changed in iOS 9.0 that can cause those crashes ?
2. Any clue how to solve this issue ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check you dictionary it may have value null for key.

Comment: You means value is null OR key is null ?

Comment: @iOS_DK, value and key aren't null (for sure).

Answer (score 2):

`atomic` on a property doesn't mean what you think it does.  `atomic` means that the property value itself (i.e. the pointer) is protected from parallel access, but it doesn't protect the contents of the dictionary at all.

If your code worked on previous versions of iOS, then it was completely by fluke.  Your code will crash randomly if you are allowing multiple threads to access a single `NSMutableDictionary` in this way.

You need to add a locking discipline of some sort between these multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use nonatomic instead of atomic

Comment: The same behavior occurs with nonatomic.